# Way to add a the visiting country flag to my website

Tags: javascript, html

I need a way to add the country flag of the visitor, is there a way to do it standalone or do I need to use a geolocation service? I appreciate all the help

Tried to use a service that turned out to be paid.

Comment: You need to use a service or a database that maps the visiting IP address to a country (unless you plan to ask the user to share their location). Unfortunately, asking for recommendations about which service/database to use is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Note that you'll get misleading results if the user is using a VPN.